# Working with two files in C

Tags: c, file, loops

I am reading a file named "text.txt" that contains a series of numbers with a space in between. I want to write in a new file named "text_nr.txt", all the numbers in "text.txt" but without repetition! My code runs in an infinite loop at the second while loop, but I can't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int n=0,m=0,nr;

    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    fp1 = fopen("text.txt","r");
    fp2 = fopen("text_nr.txt","a+");

    while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n) != EOF){
        nr=0;
        while(fscanf(fp2,"%d",&m) != EOF){
            printf("%d  %d ",m,n);
            if(n != m) continue;
            else{
                nr++;
                break;
            }
        }   
        if(nr == 0){
            fprintf(fp2,"%d ",n);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;      
}
```

Comment: At some point in the input, the format to fscanf doesn't match, so fscanf returns 0 but does  not advance the file pointer.  So it keeps reading from the same spot and returns 0 each time.

Comment: Consider using a debugger. It's fun! :-)

Comment: @WilliamPursell It does that at first time it starts to run. I have just started working with files and i don't know why that happens. Can you explain a bit further so i can understand and fix this problem ?

Comment: My general approach to these types of problems is to never use scanf, so I'm not the one to help!  IMO, `scanf` is complicated, and you will learn more if you use `fread` and `strtol` instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, I will try another approach!

Comment: you have to move stream position to begin before scanning fp2 for duplicates and to end of file when writing new value

Comment: @MikeKor I tried doing that with rewind() but nothing happened.

Comment: Another way of describing it is that the input must be well-formatted; any deviation will fail your fscanf pattern.  So either ensure the input is well-fomatted or use a better parsing pattern.

Comment: @Jerry I Think that everything is well-formatted, so i don't know why this is happening

Comment: Thank you all, I managed to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `fscanf()` return various values like `EOF` (end of file or error ) or the number of specifiers matched, `0`, `1`, ...

Rather than test for one value code needs to stop on, test against all undesired values.

```
// while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n) != EOF){
while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n) == 1){
    nr=0;
    // while(fscanf(fp2,"%d",&m) != EOF){
    while(fscanf(fp2,"%d",&m) == 1){
```

[@William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509736/working-with-two-files-in-c#comment62513357_37509736) explained it well

> At some point in the input, the format to fscanf doesn't match, so fscanf returns 0 but does not advance the file pointer. So it keeps reading from the same spot and returns 0 each time.

Infinite loop.

Comment: Creative license with `'line' -> 'like'` in first line `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop will not reach the end of file since it won't match your search string if the file starts empty.

You could do the `fscanf` and check if it's `0`  (couldn't find anything) or `EOF` (hit the end).

Comment: Doesn't it hit EOF at the first time it starts to read it if the file is empty?

Comment: Even if your at the start of an empty file, you've not hit the EOF flag, so no. (Updated the answer for clarity)

Comment: Even if the second file is not empty it still runs in an infinite loop. Itried to put some numbers in there

Comment: Wha do you get if you change "!= EOF" to "== 1" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [fseek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) function to move stream pointer inside output file.

```
 while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n) != EOF){

    fseek ( fp2, 0 , SEEK_SET );
    bool flag = false;

    while(fscanf_s(fp2,"%d",&m) != EOF){
        printf("%d  %d ",m,n);

        if(n == m) 
        {
            printf("%d = %d ", m, n);
            flag = true;


            break;
        }
    }   
    if(!flag)
    {
        fseek ( fp2, 0 , SEEK_END );
        fprintf(fp2,"%d ",n);
    }
}
```

EDIT

Another method is to store written values in array. For this you can use vector.

```
vector<int> vData;

while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n) != EOF){


    bool flag = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < vData.size(); i++)
    {
        if(vData[i] == n)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!flag)
    {
        vData.push(n);
        fprintf(fp2,"%d ",n);
    }
}
```

Comment: It still runs in an infinite loop!

Comment: I've made some changes. What numbers are you comparing?

Comment: This doesn't chane anything, the program fails here:
       while(fscanf(fp2,"%d",&m) != EOF){
               printf("%d  %d ",m,n);